# Unity5 I lost my codes inside .cs file. C# files still exist, but codes gone

Tags: c#, unity

Unity 5.1.2f1 (64-bit) version.(windows 8.1) I closed Unity. After a while ago I opened Unity and I had some errors in Console.Then I clicked the error and I realized that I lost my code in some of my C# files.Then I checked folders of my scripts and I checked date modified section of my C# files.

Here is image of my problem.

[image]

as you can see, some of file's modified date is in 7th month and other's modified date is in 8th date. Problem is I just saved those file's (7th month) just couple of days.

I had this problem before as well. That time only few changes lost and I re-code those files, but not I lost hundreds lines of codes, so I can't re-code all same. Is there any way to recover those codes?

Comment: This is why you use source control.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to recover those codes?

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Maybe. If you compiled your game, you might be able to decompile it (perhaps with something like: https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ --- your actual mileage may vary). Or depending on what exactly happened to the old file(s), perhaps you can recover them if they were deleted (http://www.howtogeek.com/169344/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-the-ultimate-guide/). Outside of that I can't think of any other options off the top of my head. The work it would take to get it back in working order from recovered files is most likely more work than just rewriting whatever was lost.

Now to address the cause of the problem; Always back everything up, and just be thankful you only lost a measly few hundred lines or so. Even if you just copy and paste files in another folder on your computer, or use git (et al) to manage your source files... you really should have a way to get back to a working state of your game when things start exploding (be it with the failed addition of new code, someone accidentallies the whole thing, or even if your hard drive decides it wants to switch careers to being a door stop).